# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

Sometimes I fetch this error during pulling something from docker hub. I have surfed the web and spent too much time to solve (or at least find the source of the problem) but my efforts went away leaving me unsolved.

There are some suggestions in different forum, github-issue like changing proxy, corporate network etc. But if the problem related to the corporate network then why this problem occurs often instead of every time I pull something in my office PC ?

**Almost every time docker works fine but often it shows this error.**

Can anyone problem my solve ?
 I am giving him advance thanks !

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yeap. But this is not a good way.

Comment: Frequently running the command 'docker pull ....' it is being solved. That means, If this error occured during pulling something from dockerhub, I run the same command again. If the problem occured in sencond time I run the command again. Frequently doing this suddenly it is started to pulling. I still don't know why this is occurred and why this is being solved in this way. If you find any way please let me know

Comment: I found a ways but there way is also not nice. Try the following solution of efranelas: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-pull-results-in-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection-client-timeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers/73064/16 it works but behind a free proxy which maybe not last forever it's also not so nice

Comment: are you doing this with or without docker proxy? And for me literally nothing works and I'm tired of this problem. Nobody knows a solution...

Comment: I simply used the docker in my company network.  Once upon a time I also tired and no such good working solution I didn't find. If you don't have any problem to remove your existing images and containers then you can use `docker system prune`  (must study first with this command before running it. It removes docker related data) and then try frequently `docker pull hello-world (or some image)`. Hopefully it will work after some 
frequent trying.

Comment: `docker system prune` poorly didn't changed anything. I got all my volumes saved on my HDD anyway. But yea... still the same garbage. @shamim

Comment: How many times you ran the command `docker pull hello-world` ?

Comment: should I do it with or without proxy for docker now? I still have the error that you had. I ran the command 5-6 times

Comment: I used normal network without configuring any manual proxy by hand. Please try more and more times. Perhaps you are taking it funny but believe me, when I run `docker pull hello-world` too many times suddenly it starts to work

Comment: I don't think that will work. I ran it more than 100 times now and it's not working.

Comment: Sadness. I am sorry not to capable of helping you bro.